# Wrong Icon on Kivy Window in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a Kivy application that otherwise works fine. In my App class, I have the following...

```
class OmissionApp(App):
    """
   Application-level class, builds the application
   """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize a new OmissionWindow.
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Some other init stuff

    def build_config(self, config):
        """
       Configure the application.
       """

        # Icon
        Config.set('kivy', 'window_icon', 'resources/icons/omission_icon.png')
        # And more stuff...

    def build(self):
        """
        This function starts the application by constructing
        it from widgets and properties.
        """

        # Set the title and icon.
        self.title = "Omission"
        self.icon = "resources/icons/omission_icon.png"

        # Create the window.
        omission_app = OmissionWindow()

        # And more...

        # Return the application.
        return omission_app
```

So, this works **just fine** on Ubuntu (16.04, 17.10), but on Microsoft Windows (7), it isn't showing the icon at all.

My file tree looks roughly like this (I left some irrelevant stuff out)...

```
.
├── omission/
│   ├── data/
│   ├── game/
│   ├── interface/
│   ├── resources/
│   │   ├── audio/
│   │   ├── content/
│   │   ├── font/
│   │   └── icons/
│   │       ├── omission_icon.ico
│   │       └── omission_icon.png
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── run.py
└── omission.spec
```

I've tried several ways of doing this (although the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.icon) indicates the code itself is right.) Also, again, it works on Ubuntu. I've tried using an `*.ico` icon file instead of the `*.png`, but no luck.

How do I get the icon working on Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given in the documentation works because it's just a filename - the actual icon file exists in the same folder as the application.

Moving the icon to the application root, and then changing the code to the following, **does** work on any system.

```
self.icon = "omission_icon.png"
```

But, since I have my icon in a subdirectory, I now am dealing with a filepath. It's really easy to forget that **paths on UNIX and Windows are not the same**. Hardcoded paths, simply put, are not portable.

Thus, I need to fix this by creating a portable system path, via `os.path`.

```
import os.path
# ...
Config.set('kivy', 'window_icon', os.path.join("omission", "resources", "icons", "omission_icon.png"))
# ...
self.icon = os.path.join("omission", "resources", "icons", "omission_icon.png")
```

The `os.path` starts from the current directory by default. In this case, that happens to be the parent of the application's directory.

> NOTE: Technically, you can leave the `"omission"` directory off, but it won't work after you've packaged with PyInstaller. The way above works either way.

Now our icon works on *any* system!

> NOTE: Yes, I know this may seem bright-blazingly obvious, but I walked in circles long enough before *spotting* the obvious that it seemed worthy of a Q&A.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by this, because windows is able to understand paths using '/' as separator, even if it's not its prefered way, you can totally "cd some/path" for example in a cmd, although completion won't work, the command will. And most of the time using '/' in paths for kivy resources works (maybe `resource_find` plays a role in this). But of course, using the correct separator is way better.

Comment: @Tshirtman I know on Windows 7 (and earlier, FWIW), cmd did *not* understand '/' as a separator, and you had to use '\'. Maybe they changed that in Win 10? All I know is, this was the only way to get the icon working with a path.

Comment: Hm, i way be wrong but i'm pretty sure i tried that on older versions and it worked. Maybe it depend on other things (locale or some configuration). Anyway, glad you found the solution :)